# Setting and accessing a custom principal with ASP.NET Core RC2 and JWT

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, claims-based-identity

I am creating a new ASP.Net Core RC2 API project and am using JWT bearer tokens.  I'm not having any trouble creating and using the token for authentication.  I have a Entity Framework 6 dbContext.  This context is also used with various other solutions.  The db context does some extra audit logging stuff for which I expect a custom principal, or at least the claims from the token.  I can see the claims on the http context, but later when the dbContext is constructed they aren't on the thread.

in Startup.cs:

```
services.AddTransient(typeof(ApiContext), (_) => new ApiContext(Configuration["Data:SqlConnection"]));
```

...

```
services.AddMvc(config =>
  {
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build();
                config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
                config.Filters.Add(new ClaimsAuthorizationFilter());
  }
  );
```

In ClaimsAuthorizationFilter:

```
ClaimsIdentity identity = context.HttpContext.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
```

identity shows all the claims.  The existing principal and its identity on the thread are generic and have no claims. I can use the identity from the context's user object to create a new principal and attach it to the current thread.

```
var auditPrincipal = new AuditPrincipal(
    identity,
    new AuditUser()
    {
...
        }
        );

   System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "authorized";
   System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal = auditPrincipal;
```

Alas in the dbContext constructor (which is called after the code above), I see only a generic principal and no claims on the identity.  I do see the thread name is the name I set earlier.

```
ClaimsIdentity identity = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
```

How can I ensure the correct principal/claims identity is available after authorization to my dbContext?